# why localhost:88/hostinfo.php not giving the desirable result?

Tags: php, xampp

I write the following script to show me the host IP but its isn't working. 
I'm using XAMPP on windows 7.

```
 <?php 
     //Gets the IP address
     $ip = getenv("REMOTE_ADDR") ; 
     Echo "Your IP is  "  . $ip; 
     ?>
```

It always shows `Your IP is ::1` .

Totally unexpected how should I fix it ?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, that's the correct IPv6 address for localhost

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`::1` and `127.0.0.1` are both ip addresses of your local machine.

Answer (score 1):

It is working as intended, that is the IPv6 loopback address (::1).  If you want it to show up as 127.0.0.1 then disable IPv6 on your computer.

Answer (score 1):

The **REMOTE**_ADDR key isn't supposed to be the host IP, it's the client's IP. You probably want `$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']`. However, I'm pretty sure they're the same in this case since you are connecting from localhost.

For further info:

```
phpinfo();
```

... or

```
print_r($_SERVER);
```